# Is there any way for administrator programmatically drop MFA for the user and let him register new MFA at a other phone? (Azure B2C custom policies)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, totp

We have Azure b2C custom policies implemented that support TOTP Multi Factor Authentication via MSFT Authenticator Mobile App from **Azure B2C custom policy starter pack**.

All good except that if the user changes or loses  mobile phone there is no way for user to re-register TOTP MFA at new phone as "extension_StrongAuthenticationAppSecretKey" claim exists.

Is there any way for administrator programmatically  drop MFA for the user and let him register new MFA at other phone?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

There are [API](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/proofing-up-users-programmatically-on-azure-ad-b2c-using-either-email-or-phone-71a71f579235) for this.